# how to intercept angular jsonp requests using httpclient

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, interceptor

I have an Interceptor for http get/post requests. It works very well.

Unfortunately it does not work for my jsonp requests / they are not caught.

Therefore I wanted to create another Interceptor that implements JsonpInterceptor.

In fact, it does not work either.

What I've done so far:

AppModule:

```
[{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyJsonpInterceptor, multi: true }],
```

MyJsonpInterceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyJsonpInterceptor implements JsonpInterceptor {

    constructor(jsonp: JsonpClientBackend) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log("intercept");
    }

}
```

Does someone know, how to intercept jsonp requests in angular 4/5 with the new httpclient?

Answer (score 2):

You have to import the JSONP intercepting module before the `HttpClientJsonpModule`

```
import { NgModule, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpClientModule,
  HttpClientJsonpModule
  } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@Injectable()
export class CustomInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomInterceptor, multi: true}
  ]
})
export class JsonpInterceptingModule {}

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule,
    JsonpInterceptingModule, // Must be before the HttpClientJsonpModule
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientJsonpModule
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, multi: true, useClass: CustomInterceptor }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(http: HttpClient){
    http.jsonp('https://archive.org/index.php?output=json', 'callback')
      .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `JsonpInterceptor` in angular maybe is the key point. Here is my solution:

1. Check your `NgModule` config, Remove `HttpClientJsonpModule`.
2. Then Add `JsonpClientBackend` and `{provide: ɵb, useFactory: ɵc}` to providers.ɵb & ɵc are alias for `JsonpCallbackContext` and `jsonpCallbackContext`
3. Then Add `{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JsonpInterceptor, multi: true},` as the last HTTP_INTERCEPTORS. Or you can use your custom interceptor overwriting JsonpInterceptor.

Hope this can help you.

Update on 2018.03.09:

You can simply do this:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: XxxInterceptor, multi: true },
  ],
})
export class XxxModule {
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    XxxModule,
    HttpClientJsonpModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Could you explain how the XxxModule's derived JsonpInterceptor should look like?
I always get this error: `'Class 'AuthInterceptorService' incorrectly implements interface 'JsonpInterceptor'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'jsonp'.`
Tried it with `implements` (interface) and with `extends`. I thought `extends` might be appropriate, since JsonpInterceptor is a class. Have I totally misunderstood something? Is it even possible to derive from angular's JsonpInterceptor and add some custom logic, or do we have to write something totally new?

Comment: Ah, I see now, I think JsonpInterceptor is not supposed to be inherited from. It's just a complete and ready-to-use interceptor to handle JSONP requests and nothing else. To be used alongside (chained with) other interceptors that are pushed to the HTTP_INTERCEPTORS multi-provider. The problem is the order of invocation here. Maybe that is what you tried to show? By placing HttpClientJsonpModule here after XxxModule, hoping that the jsonp interceptor would be called last then.
However, this did not do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how to intercept jsonp requests. And by now, I think that it's actually not of much use anyway, because JSONP requests are made by injecting a script tag into the page's html, with the requested URL as src parameter. So I think it would not be possible to add any HTTP headers. Maybe that is why JsonpInterceptor is not designed to work other than as stand-alone for any JSONP calls, ignoring every other interceptor coming afterwards.

But I at least I can explain the problem to some extent. Maybe someone else can expand upon that to provide further hints.

For making the [`http.jsonp`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#jsonp) method work one would normally simply import the [`HttpClientJsonpModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientJsonpModule), which provides the JsonpInterceptor to the [`HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HTTP_INTERCEPTORS) token.
Annotation for [`HttpClientJsonpModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientJsonpModule) from Angular docs:

`@NgModule({
        providers: [
            JsonpClientBackend,
            { provide: JsonpCallbackContext, useFactory: jsonpCallbackContext },
            { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JsonpInterceptor, multi: true },
        ]
    })`

The [`JsonpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/JsonpInterceptor) is a class implementing the [`HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) interface.
The [`JsonpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/JsonpInterceptor)  is not an interface (so you should not `implement` it, I think), and it is apparently also not designed to be derived and expanded upon. It is an injectable Angular service, which needs a provider and other stuff around it to work. This stuff is all bundlded in the [`HttpClientJsonpModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientJsonpModule), and there are probably not many use cases to use [`JsonpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/JsonpInterceptor) directly, outside the context of importing [`HttpClientJsonpModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientJsonpModule).

The [`HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HTTP_INTERCEPTORS) injection token can be assigned multiple interceptors. And these are then all applied successively on each request.
By a statement such as

    `[{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyCustomInterceptor, multi: true }],`

 you would simply add another interceptor to the chain.

But order can be important.

The [`JsonpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/JsonpInterceptor) will end the interceptor chain whenever it encounters an request of type JSONP. All interceptors coming after it will not be invoked in that case. So only request for non-JSONP go through to the other interceptors.

So it would be ideal to make sure that all other interceptors are provided *before* the JsonpInterceptor from [`HttpClientJsonpModule`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientJsonpModule).

Unfortunately I have still not found a way to do this.

But there is another problem with intercepting JSONP requests. And that is the fact that JSONP is actually just a somewhat standardized "hack" to make requests circumventing CORS security checks in the browser.
To make the request, a javascript tag is inserted into the page, with the requested url as `src` parameter, to get the content loaded.
I think it is not possible to set any headers for such a request. So that might be the reason why the JsonpInterceptor always ends the interceptor chain. Another is probably that the "last call" after the chain, which would make the actual request, cannot know that it was supposed to be done through injecting a  tag into the page, but would always only do a normal request.