# How to use Angular JSONP Interceptors

Tags: angular, jsonp, angular-http-interceptors

Anyone knows how to use:
https://angular.io/api/common/http/JsonpInterceptor

I would like to catch error through an interceptor.

Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573655/how-to-intercept-angular-jsonp-requests-using-httpclient) help ?

Comment: why don't you use HttpInterceptor instead jsonpinterceptor?

Comment: https://indepth.dev/posts/1142/exploring-the-httpclientmodule-in-angular

Comment: Unfortunately no cause JsonpInterceptingModule are not anymore in NG 11 :-(